# How to form multiple subsets of dataframes and compare and contrast

Tags: python, pandas, comparison

I have 2 dataframes, something like this:

```
data1 = pd.DataFrame({'transaction_id': {0: abc, 1: bcd, 2: efg},
 'store_number': {0: '1048', 1: '1048', 2: '1048'},
 'activity_code': {0: 'deposit-check',
  1: 'deposit-check',
  2: 'deposit-check'},
 'amount': {0: 10, 1: 11, 2: 12}})

data2 = pd.DataFrame({'transaction_id': {0: pqr, 1: qrs, 2: rst},
 'store_number': {0: '1048', 1: '1048', 2: '1048'},
 'activity_code': {0: 'deposit-check',
  1: 'deposit-check',
  2: 'deposit-check'},
 'amount': {0: 100, 1: 200, 2: 300}})
```

with more rows.

I want to take multiple subsets from each dataset and do a comparison of the total amount in each.
For example, take out 2 rows from `data1` and `data2`:

```
data1_subset1 = pd.DataFrame({'transaction_id': {0: abc, 1: bcd},
     'store_number': {0: '1048', 1: '1048'},
     'activity_code': {0: 'deposit-check',
      1: 'deposit-check'},
     'amount': {0: 10, 1: 11}})
data1_subset2 = pd.DataFrame({'transaction_id': {0: abc, 2: efg},
     'store_number': {0: '1048', 2: '1048'},
     'activity_code': {0: 'deposit-check',
      2: 'deposit-check'},
     'amount': {0: 10, 2: 12}})
```

and so on till I have all possible 2 row combinations of data1.

```
data2_subset1 = pd.DataFrame({'transaction_id': {0: pqr, 1: qrs},
     'store_number': {0: '1048', 1: '1048'},
     'activity_code': {0: 'deposit-check',
      1: 'deposit-check'},
     'amount': {0: 100, 1: 200}})
data2_subset2 = pd.DataFrame({'transaction_id': {0: pqr, 2: rst},
     'store_number': {0: '1048', 2: '1048'},
     'activity_code': {0: 'deposit-check',
      2: 'deposit-check'},
     'amount': {0: 100, 2: 300}})
```

and so on till I have all possible 2 row combinations of data2.

Now for each of these subsets, say `data1_subset1` vs `data2_subset1`, I would like to compare if the `store_number` and `activity_code` are matching using inner join and then check the difference between the total `amount` from `data1_subset1` vs `data2_subset1`.

Further I would also like to extend this to all possible size combinations. In the above example we compared all 2 row combinations. But I would like to extend this to 2 row combinations vs 3 row combinations, 2 rows vs 4, 3 vs 5, and so on till all the possibilities are checked.

Is there an efficient way of doing this in `Python / Pandas`. The first approach I had in my mind was just a nested loop using indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
from itertools import combinations

for comb in combinations(data1.index, r=2):
    print(f'combination {comb}')
    print(data1.loc[list(comb)])
```

As a function:

```
def subset(df, r=2):
    for comb in combinations(df.index, r=r):
        yield df.loc[list(comb)]
        
for df in subset(data1, r=2):
    print(df)
```

output:

```
combination (0, 1)
  transaction_id store_number  activity_code  amount
0            abc         1048  deposit-check      10
1            bcd         1048  deposit-check      11
combination (0, 2)
  transaction_id store_number  activity_code  amount
0            abc         1048  deposit-check      10
2            efg         1048  deposit-check      12
combination (1, 2)
  transaction_id store_number  activity_code  amount
1            bcd         1048  deposit-check      11
2            efg         1048  deposit-check      12
```

If you want more rows in the combination change the `r=2` parameter to the number of wanted rows.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this approach. Is there a way to specify value of r in such a way that it takes all possible combinations in range(2, len(data1)+1) or it has to be a loop for r?

Comment: You have to loop for r, check the `itertools` documentation this is called a powerset, but the implementation is using a loop ;)

Comment: I have put it in a nested loop for r for both the datasets. One of them has 40k rows and the other has 6k. Hopefully it does not take too long.

Comment: I would expect that it takes long, not because of the code, but there are ~18M combinations of 2 rows among 6k, and ~800M for 40k rows. That should take a **lot** of time (if it ever finishes)! For a powerset I would not even try with that many rows, this is just physically impossible ;)